# Functional append/extend

Tags: python

The methods `append` and `extend` in Python are not functional by nature, they modify the callee and return `None`.

Is there an alternative way to do what these methods do and get a new list as a returned value?

Consider this example:

```
def myfun(first, *args):
  for elem in [first].extend(args):
    print elem
```

Obviously, this won't work.

Is there a way to construct a new list directly with an expression, instead of being forced to write the following?

```
def myfun(first, *args):
   all_args = list(first)
   all_args.extend(args)

   for elem in all_args:
     print elem
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> def append(lst, elem):
...     return lst + [elem]
... 
>>> append([1, 2, 3], 4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> def extend(lst1, lst2):
...   return lst1 + lst2
... 
>>> extend([1, 2], [3, 4])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is that what you wanted?

You may also define your own type, which returns the list itself on these operations, in addition to change:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...   def append(self, x):
...     super(MyList, self).append(x)
...     return self
...   def extend(self, lst):
...     super(MyList, self).extend(lst)
...     return self
... 
>>> l = MyList([1, 2, 3])
>>> l.append(4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l.extend([5, 6, 7])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can rewrite that as:

```
[first] + args
```

Comment: Thanks :). Can't believe I've forgotten about this one.